# Where is zip.so when compile install php 5.3.9

Tags: php, linux, centos

I compile PHP from source on CentOS5, after doing that where can i find the zip.so?
My command is

```
cd php5.3.9
./configure --prefix=/opt/php5 --enable-zip
make -j8
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in:

```
/usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so
```

Comment: I check /usr/lib64/php/modules folder no such file :(.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have `/usr/lib/php/` folder

Comment: We can use pecl to install it.

Comment: Wow, a couple years later! Glad you found a solution.